# How to sell jewelery without getting ripped off?

Tags: jewelry, consumer-protection

Related to this question:
[If I have some old gold jewellery, is it worth it to sell it for its melt value?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/209/if-i-have-some-old-gold-jewellery-is-it-worth-it-to-sell-it-for-its-melt-value)

What is some good advice for getting a piece appraised?  Who is a typically trustworthy source to get jewelery appraised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not, there is a [National Association of Jewelry Appraisers](http://www.najaappraisers.com/).  That would be a good place to start.

Comment: ... by jove....