# Where can I buy real gold and sell it later as shown in market?

Tags: investing, markets, gold

I want to invest money in Gold.

Where can I buy Gold and sell it later when the gold prices are high? 
(high in the market as shown in market NASDAQ/NYSE)

Comment: Related and exhaustive: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10182/where-can-i-sell-some-gold-ounce-bars-i-own-without-getting-screwed?rq=1

Comment: However, as Matt mentions below gold index funds (ETFs) are a much safer, cheaper and flexible way to bet on the price of gold.

Comment: Unless your concern is that the entire world banking system is going to collapse and render paper (or digital) records of money worthless. But in that kind of situation it's unclear anyone will care much about gold; it's pretty, but it isn't a very _useful_ metal in a post-apocolyptic world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are gold index funds. I'm not sure what you mean by "real gold". If you mean you want to buy physical gold, you don't need to. The gold index funds will track the price of gold and will keep you from filling your basement up with gold bars.

Gold index funds will buy gold and then issue shares for the gold they hold. You can then buy and sell these just like you would buy and sell any share. GLD and IAU are the ticker symbols of some of these funds.

I think it is also worth pointing out that historically gold has a been a poor investment.

Comment: can you please give more details about gold index funds please.

Comment: @user206168, updated my answer

Comment: ETFs aren't gold or silver, they're paper.  If the OP is just speculating on the price of gold, then you're spot on.  However, if the OP is looking to bury it in their backyard, so to speak, ETFs will do nothing for him.